# Unable to enter a string in the text box. It just opens the browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-driver

I want to open the site www.flock.co and enter a email in the text field.However the program only opens the site and doesnt enter the email in the field.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FindByClassName {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Automation\\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://flock.co/");

        driver.findElement(By.className("_g-s-wrap")).sendKeys("farzan.s@flock.co");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_g-s-wrap` is the class of a container that includes more features (like the "Get Started" button). Use `cssSelector` to locate the `<input>` textbox

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type='email']")).sendKeys("farzan.s@flock.co");
```

Answer (score 1):

**There are many ways in which you can enter the email into  a text  field.**

1. using id
2. using name
3. xpath
4. using css selector

there are other ways too but these are the very reliable and frequently used methods.

**syntax for the methods are:**

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main-area']/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input")).sendkeys("abc@gmail.com");

    driver.findElement(By.id("give the id of the editbox by inspecting element")).sendkeys("abc@gmail.com");

    driver.findElement(By.name("give the name of the editbox by inspecting element")).sendkeys("abc@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Unfortunately my code doesn't work  with the xpath method. Made it work with the id and cssselector

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I pasted it wrong please try this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath="//*[@id="main-area"]/div[3]/div‌​[2]/form/div/div[1]/‌​input").sendkeys("ex‌​ample@example.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls use following code:-

```
  WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']"));
   ele1.sendKeys("farzan.s@flock.co");
```